# Rails 6 API mode GraphiQL shows 404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, ruby-on-rails-6, graphiql

I have a rails 6 app in api mode and I'm implementing a v2 of the api to include graphQL. I can make queries in postman just fine but when I goto http://localhost:5000/api/v2/graphiql/ I get the pretty interface but all my queries return a 404 like so:

"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"exception": "#<ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant GraphqlController>",

Have I done something wrong in my routes or is it something else?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :locations
    end
    namespace :v2 do

      if Rails.env.development?
        mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"

      end

      post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of a friend I realized the mistake. To fix this here issue you just change graphql_path: "/graphql" to the actual path. So in my case it was "/api/v2/graphql/"